# How do you insert a tab in a string?

Tags: c++

I don't really get it. Please help!

I'm a beginner.

To tab, don't you do this?

```
/t
```

Anyways, can someone please explain tabbing to me? Thanks!

Comment: Tabbing in what context?

Comment: To tab you press the Tab key

Comment: Escape Sequences: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Answer (score 19):

The correct escape sequence for a tab is `\t`